# Model is changing automatically in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, typescript2.0, angular2-changedetection

I generating dynamic drop-down based on my model and trying to set it's selected item same as data from model. I am doing all this in `*ngFor` loop. But first time after the page has loaded it is binding correct values to drop-down but once I click inside window it changes values in all drop-downs to same value and throws below error :

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'model:
>   d9cddd06-911a-4fea-9b87-f045362ede52'. Current value: 'model:
>   bd39b9a1-42f2-4db1-9639-953206062l67'

I have tried using Change Detector in `ngOnInit`,`ngAfterViewInit` and even in subscribe method where I am getting the model.

I have also tried using `ngModelChange` but no luck.
I am getting error on third line in below code:
`[(ngModel)]="data.reportTypeTemplate[i].reportTemplateId"`
I am not sure now how to fix this issue. 
Has anyone faced this issue or know the solution for this.
Let me know if more information is required.

Below is my Code :

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor = "let type of masterRTTList; let i = index">
          <label for="reportType">{{type.reportTypeName}}*</label>
          <select [(ngModel)]="data.reportTypeTemplate[i].reportTemplateId" //Here 
*ngIf="data.reportTypeTemplate.length > 0"
          class="form-control rounded-0" formControlName="reportType">
            <option value = "">Select Template</option>
            <option *ngFor="let template of type.reportTemplateName" [ngValue]="template.id">
              {{template.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
</div>
```

```
ngOnInit(){
this.apiService.get(environment.api_url, 'GetReports/')
      .subscribe(templates => {
        this.masterRTTList = templates 
      });
}
```

Comment: try putting your service call in ngAfterViewInit. Apparently the model is changing which angular is still running its internal update cycle

Comment: @Jinish I tried that. But its not working.

Comment: @Jinish Do you have any other solution for this?